# Apollo GraphQL Server vs graphql-sequelize vs from scratch?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm a beginner to javascript and GraphQL, looking to implement a simple app that interacts with a MySQL database and wraps a 3rd party REST API. GraphQL seems like the right fit, and Javascript has first party support.

To get started, should I use [Apollo's GraphQL Server](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-server) or [mickhansen's graphql-sequelize](https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize) (with his dataloader-sequelize) or [write one from scratch](https://www.reindex.io/blog/building-a-graphql-server-with-node-js-and-sql/)?

In all cases it seems to use sequelize under the hood, which mickhansen is a major contributor to.

I'm looking for the advice and analysis of more experienced javascript and GraphQL programmers.

I realise the final decision is subjective but I'm looking for a thought out pro/con of all 3 different solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not to start writing your server from scratch, but to use existing libraries and seed projects. Personally, I use Typescript with the Apollo stack, combined with several other libraries for splitting the schema to files, and auto-generating types.
This [post](https://medium.com/@tomyitav/graphql-server-for-enterprise-development-675d2ff2d0ed) demonstrates how to modularize your graphql server code, providing a seed project you can clone. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using Apollo GraphQL with Sequelize. Sequelize is your ORM to interact with the DB, it can function with Apollo which takes care of your GraphQL. GraphQL is a thin api layer anyway. One problem i have been running into is dataloader implementation with vanilla Sequelize. I am trying to figure it out to get it working. I am hoping to work through it this week.

Comment: Is Apollo GraphQL the same as GraphQL server? I hear it is used interchangeably. Just looking for clarification.

Comment: For the most part it is, it's apollos implementation of it. It comes with its own set of things but you can do everything that a graphql server can do on it. It has other features but so far i've been liking apollo

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I figured it does the same thing and has other features.